# Swift constraint using multiplier working with trailing but not leading

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint, swift5

I have the following two texts the Timer constraint works fine. However when doing the complete same with Score just using leading constraint it's stuck.

Anyone has an idea what I'm missing?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because leading has zero value unlike trailing which = view width , so applying multiplier to zero results in a zero

You can make it with centerX / trailing also

[image]

Comment: Why does it work for the text "Timer" with a constant of zero too?

Comment: as timer has a leading value higher than 0 , so it's leading can be affected by a multiplier

Comment: So what should I do to fix Score?

Comment: it will go to the right in proportional to screen width as centerX value is different among devices

Answer (score 0):

Just change the leading Constrain of Score to Superview.Trailing instead of Superview.Leading :

[image]

And then set the Score constraint multiplier to 6.27.
I will update the answer with the calculation I made shortly.

**UPDATE:**

The multiplier of Score.Leading constant to Superview.Traling constant is :
multiplier = View.width / (View.width - View.width / 1.2)

In my case the View width in iPhone X is 414

414 / 1.2 = 345

414 - 345 = 69

414 / 69 = multiplier